# Unable to import source classes in scala project with gradle dependencies in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, gradle, scalatest

This is the structure of my project

`src
    main
        scala
            com.abc
                1.2
                    Album.scala
                    Artist.scala
    test
        scala
            com.abc
                1.2
                    AlbumTest.scala`

Spec File

```
import org.scalatest._

class AlbumSpec extends FlatSpec {

it should "can add an Artist object to the album" in {
  val album = Album("Thriller", 1981,Artist("Michael", "Jackson"))

}

}
```

Album.scala

```
case class Album (name: String, year: Int,artist: Artist)
```

Artist.scala

`case class Artist(firstName: String, lastName: String)`

I am not able to create objects of Album and Artist in my spec file

IntelliJ Version: 2017.2

Gradle Version: 3.4.1

scalatest: scalatest_2.11:2.2.6

scala : 2.11.6

Comment: What do you mean that you're "not able to create objects"?

Comment: I was not able to create objects of my source classes, in test module. Evidently it was due to a spring milestone jar being used by a project dependency. It was showing a warning and my superior asked me to ignore it,but that was the culprit. I changed it to a version from central repository, Its working now.